# Swift, decoding "iso-8859-5"

Tags: ios, swift, string, decoding

I receive a line in the format "iso-8859-5", but I can not decode it correctly. I think the problem is that I'm not converting the string correctly to data. But I do not know how to correctly convert a string to a data, without using a encoding.

Please help.

```
let string = "\\X2\\041F043504400435043A0440044B044204380435\\X0\\:\\X2\\042D\\X0\\_\\X2\\041F043B043804420430\\X0\\"
let encodingName = "iso-8859-5"

let cfe = CFStringConvertIANACharSetNameToEncoding(encodingName as CFString!)
if cfe != kCFStringEncodingInvalidId {
    let encoding = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(cfe)
    let decString: String = NSString(data: string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, encoding: String.Encoding(rawValue: UInt(encoding)).rawValue)! as String  
    print("string: " + decString)
}
```

Comment: What is your expected output in this case? Your input string doesn't contain any cyrillic characters, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Gereon expected output is "Перекрытие:Э_Плита". I use OPENIFCTOOLS. 
http://www.buildingsmart-tech.org/implementation/get-started/string-encoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your encoded string consists of sequences 16-bit Unicode values (the hex digits between the `\X2\` and `\X0` separators). When you extract the values from that, you'll get this:

```
let bytes = [ 0x041F, 0x0435, 0x0440, 0x0435, 0x043A, 0x0440, 0x044B, 0x0442, 0x0438, 0x0435 ]
```

which you can convert to a String using this:

```
var s = ""
s.unicodeScalars.append(contentsOf: bytes.flatMap { UnicodeScalar($0) } )
print(s) // prints "Перекрытие"
```

Comment: Thank you! You really helped!

Answer (score 1):

You can't stick arbitrary bytes into a string literal in Swift. You need to store it as a array of `UInt8` or as a `Data`. Example:

```
let bytes: [UInt8] = [0x41, 0xF0, 0x43, 0x50, 0x44, 0x43, 0x50, 0x43, 0xA0, 0x44]
let data = Data(bytes)
let cfEncoding = CFStringConvertIANACharSetNameToEncoding("iso-8859-5" as CFString)
let nsEncoding = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(cfEncoding)
let string = NSString(data: data, encoding: nsEncoding) as String
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I tried it like you said, but the result is not the one I expect.
`let bytes: [UInt8] = [0x04, 0x1F, 0x04, 0x35, 0x04, 0x40, 0x04, 0x35, 0x04, 0x3A, 0x04, 0x40, 0x04, 0x4B, 0x04, 0x42, 0x04, 0x38, 0x04, 0x35]`

Decoded string: "5@5:@KB85"